# What is the function try block handler?

Tags: c++

I came across this question recently - *What is function try block handler?*

Also, where would it be useful?

Comment: yes, i did that ... my doubt is - why is it there, whats the real usage for this?

Comment: http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/comphelp/v7v91/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.vacpp7a.doc/language/ref/clrc17fn_try_block_hndlers.htm

Answer (score 3, accepted):

a function written like this:

```
void fun ()
try 
{
.....
.....
}
catch(SomeException & e)
{
....
....
}
```

is called a function try block.

This is typically used with constructors with initialization lists to catch the exception thrown during the construction of an object constructed in the initialization list.

Answer (score 4):

[Here](http://www.informit.com/guides/content.aspx?g=cplusplus&seqNum=493) you can find a good explanation.

It could be useful in an initialization list of a constructor:

```
struct A
{
private:
  std::string s;
public:
  A( int value ) try : s( boost::lexical_cast<std::string>( value ) ) {}
  catch ( boost::bad_lexical_cast ) { /* handle lexical_cast exception here */ }
};
```